# getting database error no such table: crave_crave_data

Tags: django, migration, django-south

After sync db i updated the model.py file

```
class crave_data(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    publication_name=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    discription=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post
```

i am using south. I used all commands of south migration still i am getting the same error.

and i am not able to view the sqlite.db file also. sqlite.db file is not present over there.
when i use sqlall i am getting only one table info "facebook_facebookuser" other two tables i am not able to view.
used this also

```
manage.py schemamigration crave --initial
manage.py migrate crave
manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto
```

still problem not solved.
and why its not creating the sqlite.db file after syncdb?
Please help me out.

Comment: I can not quite get what you mean clearly, you mean after execute `python manage.py syncdb`, but there is no sqlite.db exists? Is there any error message?

Comment: no,,,,, But i can able to use admin and before i saved some data over there also,,,,,,,,,

Comment: did you ever view the crave_data table in the sqlite.db? Or, only can not be viewed after you update the crave_data?

Comment: no i dont have db file over there ,,,,,,,,, how can i view?